# Show title of element but pass through click

Tags: html, css

I need a CSS-only solution to link to Stackoverflow anywhere in the box but show the title of my `.title` element on mouse over anyways. If I set the title `position: relative`, give it a higher z-index than my anchor and set `pointer-events: none`, I only see the title of my anchor. So how can I have a completely clickable anchor in my wrapper but see the title of my `.title` element **without** changing my mark up?

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4444ff;
}

.title {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4466ff;
}

a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title" title="This is a shortened String">This is a shortened Stri...</div>
  <a title="visit Stackoverflow" href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: to see a title you should trigger the hover, so i think it's not possible to hover an element and see title of another one

Comment: it's not possible as you are positioning `<a>` on top of `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a way to achieve it without changes to your mark up but here are some possible solutions:

**1. Custom tooltip**

Check out the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/aska-g/pen/GOjyby?editors=1100).

Add `data-tooltip` and `data-tooltip-position` attributes to your wrapper in HTML and style it as you please in CSS. Add `display:none` to your title attribute as we want to override it with our customised tooltip.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" data-tooltip="This is a shortened String" data-tooltip-position="top">
  <div class="title">This is a shortened Stri...</div>

  <a title="Stackoverflow" href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4444ff;
}

.wrapper title {
  display: none;
}

.title {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4466ff;
}

a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

[data-tooltip] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px;
}
/* Tooltip styling */
[data-tooltip]:before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: lightgray;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Dynamic horizontal centering */
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before {
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/* Dynamic vertical centering */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before {
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

/* Tooltip arrow styling/placement */
[data-tooltip]:after {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}
/* Dynamic horizontal centering for the tooltip */
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
/* Dynamic vertical centering for the tooltip */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after {
    bottom: 50%;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0;
    border-top-color: lightgray;
}
/* Show the tooltip when hovering */
[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
    display: block;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

**2. Change your anchor's title**

Modify the `title` of your anchor to equal the title of your div.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title" title="This is a shortened String">This is a shortened Stri...</div>
  <a title="This is a shortened String" href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
</div>
```

**3. Assign title to your wrapper**

Instead of assigning a `title` attribute to your `.title` class, put it on your wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper" title="This is a shortened String">
  <div class="title">This is a shortened Stri...</div>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, using `alt` on anchor is not allowed by the spec. Well, it appears there is no good solution so I will go with **2.** I guess. Thank you

Comment: You're right about the `alt`. Another workaround for solution 3 would be to keep the desired title of the anchor and add `a[title]:hover {
  display:none;
}` to your CSS. I'll correct my answer too.